# Is there a way to detect if crossrider extension is disabled/enabled by user

Tags: crossrider

Is there a way to run a callback after crossrider extension is disabled/enabled from browser. Chrome provides api for this like :
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#event-onEnabled

Is there any api in crossrider for checking this.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the Crossrider API does not provide methods for handling the extension disabled/enabled events and the native Chrome API is unlikely to work as the extension do not include the required "management" permissions.

However, it's a great idea and hence I have submitted a request for it with the product team who will consider it for future releases.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]